# Creating a routesheet with multiple models in one table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to create a routesheet app for my logistics managing django app. Here are my models:

```
class RouteSheet(models.Model):
    start_program = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Start program')
    end_program = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='End program')
    start_km = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Starting kilometer')
    end_km = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ending kilometer')
    truck = models.ForeignKey(Trucks, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Truck')
    trailer = models.ForeignKey(Trailers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Trailer')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='routesheet_created')


class LoadingSheet(models.Model):
    loading_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Loading time')
    loading_km = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Loading kilometer')
    loading_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Loading location')
    route_sheet = models.ForeignKey(RouteSheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='loading_sheet', verbose_name='Route sheet')
    loading_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media/routesheet/loading-images/', verbose_name='Loading image')

class UnloadingSheet(models.Model):
    unloading_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Unloading time')
    unloading_km = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Unloading kilometer')
    unloading_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Unloading location')
    route_sheet = models.ForeignKey(RouteSheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='unloading_sheet', verbose_name='Route sheet')
    unloading_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media/routesheet/unloading-images/', verbose_name='Unloading image')

class FuelSupply(models.Model):
    supply_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Supply time')
    supply_km = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Supply kilometer')
    supply_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Supply location')
    supply_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Supply size (in liters)')
    supply_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Supply cost')
    supply_company = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Supply company')
    supply_observations = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Observations')
    route_sheet = models.ForeignKey(RouteSheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='supply_sheet', verbose_name='Route sheet')
    supply_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media/routesheet/fuel-supply-images/', verbose_name='Supply image')
```

What I'm trying to achieve is have a start_program where I start when creating a route sheet with a form for starting the program where I add the start_km, truck, trailer, and for end will be a finish-routesheet button that takes me to a end form with only end_km.

The LoadingSheet, UnloadingSheet, and FuelSupply are part of the table body, where I would have a button for each that takes me to a form where I add each fields, and are displayed as table data.

I created the forms:

```
    class RouteSheetForm(AddClass, forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = RouteSheet
        fields = ['start_km', 'truck', 'trailer']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['truck'].widget = forms.Select(choices=[(truck.id, truck.registration_plate) for truck in Trucks.objects.all()], attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['trailer'].widget = forms.Select(choices=[(trailer.id, trailer.registration_plate) for trailer in Trailers.objects.all()], attrs={'class': 'form-control'})

class LoadingSheetForm(AddClass, forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = LoadingSheet
        fields = ['loading_km', 'loading_location', 'loading_image']


class UnloadingSheetForm(AddClass, forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = UnloadingSheet
        fields = ['unloading_km', 'unloading_location', 'unloading_image']

class FuelSupplyForm(AddClass, forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = FuelSupply
        fields = ['supply_km', 'supply_location', 'supply_size', 'supply_cost', 'supply_company', 'supply_observations', 'supply_image']
```

and here are my views:

```
    class RouteSheetListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = RouteSheet
    template_name = 'routesheet/routesheet_table.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.status=='employee':
            queryset = RouteSheet.objects.filter(created_by=user)
        else:
            queryset = RouteSheet.objects.all()
        return queryset
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        latest_routesheet = RouteSheet.objects.latest('id')
        context['latest_routesheet'] = [latest_routesheet]
        return context


class CreateRouteSheetView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'routesheet/routesheet_start.html'
    form_class = RouteSheetForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'the route sheet has been successfully created!')
        return reverse('routesheet')
    
class LoadingSheetListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = LoadingSheet
    template_name = 'routesheet/routesheet_table.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.status=='employee':
            queryset = LoadingSheet.objects.filter(created_by=user)
        else:
            queryset = LoadingSheet.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        loadings = LoadingSheet.objects.all()
        context['loadings'] = [loadings]
        return context

    
class CreateLoadingSheetView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'routesheet/loading_form.html'
    form_class = LoadingSheetForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.route_sheet = RouteSheet.objects.latest('id')
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'the route sheet has been successfully created!')
        return reverse('routesheet')


class LoadingSheetListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = UnloadingSheet
    template_name = 'routesheet/routesheet_table.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.status=='employee':
            queryset = UnloadingSheet.objects.filter(created_by=user)
        else:
            queryset = UnloadingSheet.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        unloadings = UnloadingSheet.objects.all()
        context['unloadings'] = [unloadings]
        return context
```

**My question is, can this be done in one table and should I make a ListView and CreateView for each model, can it be done in one function or one ListView, CreateView?**